# 1px border around a div when transform: scale occurs

Tags: html, css

I am having some problems with white 1px border when transform: scale occurs on it or when the width of browser changes. It is visible only around first and third block (yellow one and the one with the 'H' letter on it) and ONLY in chrome and safari browser, in firefox everything looks good though!

I was looking for similar topics and I realized that a lot of people had this problem but actually there was no answer that could help in my case.

-webkit-transform:translateZ and -webkit-backface-visibility in CSS did not work.

Here's an url to a site:

http://wemakeithappen.pl/connect/

Thanks a lot for help! I hope someone can fix it:)

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: Not exactly an answer but a workaround would be adding negative margin to the row i.e. `margin-bottom: -1px` for example on `.first-row, .second-row, .third-row`

Comment: @tohood87 it helped with bottom margin, thanks a lot! but there is still a white border when u click into yellow element. any ideas anyone?